# Conditionally rename keys in a list and convert into a map?

Tags: clojure

Is there a simple way to convert a list of key-values into a map while also renaming the keys in a conditional way?

Example:

```
 [{:count 4, :happened "true"} {:count 1, :happened "false"}]
```

converted into:

```
{:happened-count: 4, :didnt-happen-count: 1}
```

I'm kinda close:

```
user=> (def foo [{:count 4, :happened "true"} {:count 1, :happened "false"}])

user=> (into {} (map (juxt :happened :count) foo))
{"true" 4, "false" 1}
```

edit:  This works, but it is ugly.  Hoping for something nicer:

```
(clojure.set/rename-keys (into {} (map (juxt :happened :count) foo)) {"true" :happened-count "false" :didnt-happen-count})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would rather advice using simple reduction

```
(def mapping {"true" :happened-count "false" :didnt-happen-count})

(reduce #(assoc % (-> %2 :happened mapping) (:count %2)) {} data)

;;=> {:happened-count 4, :didnt-happen-count 1}
```

Comment: This seems the most straight forward!

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, you can use the `->>` macro to see the transformation as a pipeline:

```
(->> [{:count 4, :happened "true"} {:count 1, :happened "false"}]
     (map (juxt :happened :count))
     (into {})
     (clojure.set/rename-keys {"true"  :happened-count
                               "false" :didnt-happen-count}))
```

eg. first extract the values, then group them into a new map, then rename the keys

Comment: doesn't rename keys take the arg in the first position?  So `->>` wouldn't work, but maybe `as->` would?

Comment: The `->>` macro takes a value (the list of maps in this case) and passes that as the last argument to the next form (the `map` line) and the result of that is passed as the last argument to the `into` form, and the result of that is passed as the last argument to the call to `rename-keys`. I tested it on the REPL

Comment: @marathon is right. `rename-key` is used as `(rename-keys map kmap)` so first parameter is now renamed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a million ways to approach a problem like this.  I like to be explicit about the steps.  Here is how I would think about it:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [data       [{:count 4, :happened "true"}
                    {:count 1, :happened "false"}
                    {:count 5, :happened "true"}
                    {:count 3, :happened "false"}]
        data-split (group-by :happened data)
        sum-count  (fn [recs]
                     (reduce +
                       (mapv :count recs)))
        result     {:happened-num     (sum-count (get data-split "true"))
                    :didnt-happen-num (sum-count (get data-split "false"))}]
    (is= data-split
      {"true"  [{:count 4, :happened "true"}
                {:count 5, :happened "true"}],
       "false" [{:count 1, :happened "false"}
                {:count 3, :happened "false"}]} )
    (is= result {:happened-num 9, :didnt-happen-num 4})))
```

I added multiple records for the true & false cases, as I that seems like a more typical use case.